# Far Negative Lookbehind

Tags: java, regex

How do I change my [pattern](http://regexr.com?33k0v) to look further back in the string?

When the word "paragraph" is behind the pattern (alpha) then the match is false, otherwise it's true.

So for example this would have **5 matches**:

> acts on behalf of any person referred to in act (a), (b), (c), (d) or
>   (e) paragraph (f);

They would be: `(a)` `(b)` `(c)` `(d)` `(e)`

And this would have **0 matches**:

> acts on behalf of any person referred to in paragraph (a), (b), (c),
>   (d) or (e);

Comment: I didn't understand the 2nd paragraph of your question. :)

Comment: @ThreaT yep, better, you could think your problem in an opposite way. try to match those "false" case. it could make it a lot easier. check my answer for detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible for any length with a simple lookbehind. Java regex flavor only allow finite-length lookbehind (i.e. you can do `(?<=x{2,10})` but not `(?<=x*)`).

If you can reduce the problem to “the word `paragraph` should not appear in the 100 letters preceding `(a)`”, that works:

```
(?<!paragraph.{0,100})\([a-z]\)
```

If you really want unbounded distance *and* if your regex is flexible and can start at the beginning of the input and match only one `(ref)`, you can approximate the wanted behavior with negative look-ahead (which needs not be finite):

```
^(?!.*?paragraph.*?\([a-z]\)).*?\([a-z]\)
```

Will match `test test (a)` but not `paragraph test (a)`.

That is a trick though that can become quite complex to maintain, has downsides (like matching only once) and ultimately there are probably better ways to solve your problem. For instance, you could match all those `([a-z])` then check whether the string contains `paragraph`, eliminating all matches that come after its position.

PS: instead of `Pattern.compile("[aA][bB][cC]")`, consider using `Pattern.compile("abc", Pattern.CASE_INSENSISIVE)` or `Pattern.compile("(?i)abc")` (if the whole regex is case-insensitive) or `Pattern.compile("(?i:abc)dEf")` (if only `abc` is case-insensitive).

Comment: Can you try that in `www.gskinner.com/RegExr`? For some reason `test test (a)` and `paragraph test (a)` don't work for me

Comment: RegExr uses ActionScript 3's regex flavor: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/03/regexr_free_onl.html

Comment: Yes. Can you please post a link to it demonstrating your pattern.

Comment: yes, the questions says before. But `(a) paragraph (b)` won't (not even on `(a)`), that's one of the limitations… Therefore I would not recommend this approach blindly.

Answer (score 0):

you could do in this way:

(I ignored the case intensive part, you could add by yourself)

```
".*Paragraph.*\\(a\\)"
```

This is checking if there is match for your `FALSE` case. which is, a `(a)` with `paragraph` ahead.

then you check if the line match the regex above, if true, then you skip, if false, then you take it.

test with grep: (-v is for displaying not-matched lines)

```
kent$  cat test.txt
(a)
Paragraph (a)
(b) (c)
foo bar Paragraph (a) (b)
foo bar Paragraph (some) (a) (b)
foo bar (a) (b) Paragraph (c)

kent$  grep -v '.*Paragraph.*\(a\)' test.txt
(a)
(b) (c)
foo bar (a) (b) Paragraph (c)
```

there is a little problem is, if the line has no `Paragraph` and no `(a)`, would be matched as well. I think this is also easy to be fixed in your java program by something like:

```
if (!m.find() && line.indexOf("(a)")>0) ...your match
```

Comment: Kent can you try and run this pattern on `www.gskinner.com/RegExr` and share a link to it

Comment: @ThreaT I was avoiding to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// If "paragraph" (case insensitive) does not appear before any (<alpha>)
// It means that "paragraph" (case insensitive) will appear after one (<alpha>)
// OR it does not appear at all in the string.
if (!str.matches("(?s)(?:(?!\\([a-z]+\\)).)*(?i:paragraph).*")) {
    // Use the Matcher loop to extract the text that matches pattern "\\([a-z]+\\)"
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\([a-z]+\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Just check that `paragraph` doesn't appear before all the `(<alpha>)` before extracting all the `(<alpha>)`. This will work for any length of the string.