# Regex Negative Lookbehind

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Far Negative Lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625969/far-negative-lookbehind)

I've been trying for days to get this to work. I had a similar question yesterday but it hasn't really helped. Basically I'm trying to create a pattern that matches:

`(a)` where "a" can be any letter like: `[a-zA-Z]`. However, this should not match: `paragraph (a), (b), (c), (d) or (e);` because it starts with the word `paragraph`. If it were just `(a), (b), (c), (d) or (e)` then it should result in 5 matches being found.

http://regexr.com?33ka2

Comment: `paragraph (a), (b), (c), (d) or (e);` should not match at all, or only `(b)`, `(c)`, `(d)` and `(e)` should match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
^(?![^()]*paragraph).*?\([a-zA-Z]\)
```

use `multiline` option

---

You can instead break down the problem by first taking all the lines that doesn't contain `paragraph` and then collect the individual `([a-zA-Z])`

```
 Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^(?!.*paragraph).*$",Pattern.MULTILINE);
 Matcher m=p.matcher(input);
 while(m.find())
 {
     Matcher mm=Pattern.compile("\\([a-zA-Z]\\)").matcher(m.group(0));
     while(mm.find())
     {
         System.out.println(mm.group(0));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to include `multiline` in the pattern somehow? `(?m)`

Comment: @ThreaT yes..you are right..

Comment: How can I make it so that it finds 5 matches instead of 1? http://regexr.com?33kb6 - One for each `(alpha)`

Comment: @ThreaT you can make `.*` to `.*?`.that would solve your problem..try it in java based regex engine **not** on gskinner

Comment: This should match only the first instace, not those `(alpha)`[i.e., `If it were just (a), (b), (c), (d) or (e)...`] comes after paragraph word.

Comment: @Cylian thx to point it out..would look into it now